# removing invisible character in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I notice in my excel I have an extra space in random places. 
So I copy the value and save it in notepad++. 
then I open using HEX Editor. so I found out it is actually not a space (HEX 20)

So the blank space is actually HEX C2. which is Â But in excel this is invisible.

I am using Excel 2016

How can I get rid of this?

they are scattered randomly ... thank you

Comment: try the TRIM() and CLEAN() functions when referencing cells?  pnuts solution would be better though.

Comment: tried find and replace but it can't find HEX C2 for some reason. What I did is to replace Â with nothing.. does not work. But substitute Char(160) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using substitute with char formula to remove the extra space.
I guess you have to use char(160) which is blank space.

```
=SUBSTITUTE("Cell Reference",CHAR(160),"")
```

If you dont know the code you can use below formula to get the char code of your blank text.

```
=CODE(RIGHT("Your Cell",1))
```